# Can anyone get conn.Trace = true to work for sql-net-pcl 1.2.0?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I think I have now tried everything possible.  Just tried with the sample todo PCL project by adding:

```
database = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite> ().GetConnection ();
database.Trace = true;
```

That doesn't work either.  In fact nothing I have done so far enables database tracking to appear in the Application Output window.

Would appreciate any suggestions people may have that could help me.